# is there any solution to call the next pointer in an implemented LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I am coding a queue that uses the built in LinkedList.  I want to sort it before it can be dequeued.My solution is trying to use a merge sort.This is my code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Queue {
    LinkedList<TransactionDetails> priorityList;

    public Queue() {
        priorityList = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void enqueue(TransactionDetails elements){
        if (priorityList.size() != 0 ){
            priorityList.addFirst(elements);
        }else {
            priorityList.addLast(elements);
        }
    }

        
       
    public void dequeue(){
        TransactionDetails head = priorityList.get(0);
        TransactionDetails Mid = getMid(head);
    }

    TransactionDetails getMid(TransactionDetails head) {
        TransactionDetails midPrev = null;
        while (head != null && head.next != null) {
            midPrev = (midPrev == null) ? head : midPrev.next;
            head = head.next.next;
        }
        TransactionDetails mid = midPrev.next;
        midPrev.next = null;
        return mid;
    }

    

}
```

My TransactionDetails object contains a long variable where I want to compare the values and sort it. However , I can't access the next method in the built in LinkedList.Is there any solution to implement my idea? I've tried Iterator but it seems not useful in my case.

Do voice out if you think there is an alternative solution that is more efficient than my solution.Thank you!

Comment: Use the standard java.util.PriorityQueue?

Comment: Java's native linked list class does not provide the equivalent of [C++ std::list::splice()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice). It doesn't provide a way to move nodes within a list or between lists. Java's iterators can't be shallow copied, assignment just sets another reference to the same iterator object. If using iterators to a Java native linked list, deleting or inserting nodes will invalidate all iterators (except for an iterator used to do the insert or delete). You would need to implement your own linked list class to get around these limitations.

Comment: *"alternative solution that is more efficient"*: if your solution does not work, how could we compare efficiency??